# Can I return pivot table output in MySQL (MySQL dynamic pivot table)?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a problem ,i have a simple table.

```
SELECT DayOfWeek,date,col1,col2,col3 FROM tdb;
```

the result is:

```
    DayOfWeek |   date      |   col1      |   col1      |   col3
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Friday    | 2022-01-07  |     1       |   41        |   NULL
    Saturday  | 2022-01-08  |     20      |   38        |   1458
```

But I wanna change row to column ,I am trying by (case and union but i can not do it)
for details i wrote this query
This SQL gives me ,it is not dynamic:!!! How can I do it?

```
SELECT date,DayOfWeek,  
        SUM( CASE WHEN date> =now() THEN date END ) AS  '2022-01-08',
        SUM( CASE WHEN date> =subdate(now(),interval 1 day) THEN date END ) AS  '2022-01-07' 
    FROM tdb
    GROUP BY date;
```

I wanna show the result is:

```
       date       | 2022-01-07  |  2022-01-08    
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
       DayOfWeek  | Friday      |   Saturday   
       col1       | 1           |  20 
       col2       | 41          |  38 
       col3       | NULL        |  1458
```

Comment: Convert it on the client side using its report subsystem. This is more simple..

Comment: What do you mean it is not dynamic? Btw, such transforamtions are better suited for some kind of a BI / reporting application, not for sql.